# Is keigo/formal only used at the end of sentences?

Tags: grammar

So I was going over から, and I noticed how all the sentences had like 病気だから, or りんごがない in the middle of the sentences, and then they had keigo/formal at the end with ます and です. So that got me thinking, is keigo/formal just never used in the middle of setences, and it's always the "short" version that is used?

For example:

> 今日は病気だから、運動しません。

Comment: It can be used in the middle. There are many such examples that you can find on Tatoeba.

Answer (score 4):

Your use of the word “keigo” is a bit misleading. When people hear it, they usually don’t think of です and ます although they are technically part of “keigo”. I will call them polite forms as opposed to plain forms, which you called “short” versions.

Some conjunctives do require a plain form but から is not one of them. You can use a polite form before it.

> 今日は病気ですから、運動しません。

Answer (score 2):

No - There are many examples where the formal is used in the front of the sentence (ご~) or in the middle. Your sentence could say 「今日は病気なので、運動しません。」 without changing meaning also.