# Confused about mix of polite/impolite forms in genki workbook

Tags: grammar

While doing [these exercises](https://sethclydesdale.github.io/genki-study-resources/lessons-3rd/lesson-9/workbook-7/) on the particle から from Seth Clythesdale's online Genki Workbook, I noticed that in the provided answer to the exercise I, question 3, polite and impolite forms are mixed, at least to my untrained Japanese abilities:

> みなみさんは踊るのが上手だから、すごく人気があります。
>
> Minami is very popular because she is good at dancing.

We have あります at the end, but before the から, we have だ and not です. Is だから different from から? Because in the [lesson 9 of the textbook](https://sethclydesdale.github.io/genki-study-resources/#lesson-9), only から is discussed, but not だから.

Comment: This isn't "impolite".  It's plain form.  It's also the form which is used in nonsentence final clauses.  Japanese doesn't beat you over the head about politeness.  These ます/です forms are usually only seen at the end of the sentence, not in the middle of a sentence.  Occasionally, you might hear otherwise.  But to speak that way stands out as quite different.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is keigo/formal only used at the end of sentences?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/99014/is-keigo-formal-only-used-at-the-end-of-sentences)

Answer (score 2):

Like others have mentioned in the comments and such, its possible to have ですから and still end with a polite form (e.g あります), but you will mainly come across the plain form with a polite form ending like your [workbook practice problems](https://sethclydesdale.github.io/genki-study-resources/lessons/lesson-9/grammar-10/) in my experience.

But I wanted to address this portion of your question since I see it equally as important, if not more important:

> Is だから different from から? Because in the lesson 9 of the textbook, only から is discussed, but not だから

Now I cannot speak on when / how Genki teaches you this as I have never used it before, but から can mean 2 different things depending on what comes before it.

1. から can mean "from" if there is a noun beforehand without だ (です in polite form)

Example:

> 学校から来ました。
>
> I came from school.

Our noun before から is 学校 (school) and since there is no だ this means "from" in this case.

2. から means "because" if there is a verb, い adjective, な adjective, or noun beforehand. However, for this meaning, the な adjective and noun will have a だ (です in polite form) before the から.

Example:

> 黒い猫だから好きです。
>
> I like it because its a black cat.

Our noun before から is 猫 (cat) and since there is a だ before the から this means "because" in this case.

Just as a side note, those workbook practice problems linked above seem to all focus on the "because" meaning / usage.

Answer (score 0):

I think technically it's a mistake. E.g. one should instead say みなみさんは踊るのが上手なので、すごく人気があります。

Now that said, there are situations where you are using keigo but there is not a big difference in terms of social status. In this case, it's not uncommon to "lower" the level of politeness.

At least I do it even intentionally. By doing this, you can signal to the conversation partner that you want a more frank conversation, and it can even be used to prime the conversation partner before trying to switch to タメ語.

Comment: This answer would be better with an explanation of the reasoning behind thinking it's a mistake, or reasoning about the idea for correcting/improving it.